# PyQt5 - Display lines from txt file into multiple QTextEdit's

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I'm new in pyqt5 and I'm working on a gui that runs tasks from a txt file (each line is a task) and I have 8 QTextEdit's that i already created ,i want after clicking the "execute all tasks" button to display each line into a QTextEdit (for example the first line will be shown in the first QTextEdit, the second line in the second QTextEdit ..., but the ninth line will be displayed in the first QTextEdit , the tenth line in the second QTextEdit ...) and keep looping thru my eight QTextEdit's.

Let's suppose i have a file with 10 lines :

hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
hello5
hello6
hello7
hello8
hello9
hello10

here is the result i'm trying to reach :

[res1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctxH4.png)

[res2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvN0N.png)

[Please check my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VWo2.png)

I tried this but my when i click the button " execute all tasks " the form crashes returning this message :

clearzsh:  killed     python3 main.py

class Task(QDialog):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Task, self).__init__()
    loadUi("task.ui", self)
    self.exit.clicked.connect(self.taskscreen)
    self.all_b.clicked.connect(self.execute_all)

def taskscreen(self) :
    login = MainScreen()
    widget.addWidget(login)
    widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    widget.setFixedHeight(620)
    widget.setFixedWidth(1080)

def execute_all(self) :
    
    all_textedit = []
    t1 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t2 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t3 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t4 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t5 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t6 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t7 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    t8 = QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
    w = [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8]
    
    while not w in all_textedit :
        if isinstance(w, QTextEdit):
            all_textedit.append(w)
            w = w.nextInFocusChain()
        
    with open("taches.txt") as file :
        lines = file.readlines()

    it = itertools.chain(w)
    for line in lines :
        all_textedit = next(it)
        all_textedit.append(line)
```

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QStackedWidget()

task = Task()

widget.addWidget(task)

widget.setFixedHeight(600)

widget.setFixedWidth(1024)

widget.show()

try :

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

except :

```
print("bye")
```

*Thanks for your support !*

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't make a lot of sense. Specifically, the `while not w in all_textedit`: `w` is a list. Also, why are you trying to use `nextInFocusChain()`? Besides, if you want an appropriate answer, you should provide a [mre] (including the UI); please note: read that link *very carefully*, the example should be *both* reproducible ***and*** minimal.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help i edited the post and added two more images that shows the result i want. and about that function i found it on pyqt forum soo ..

Comment: @aymane_da  Your code is not reproducible as it stands.  Can you please provide a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: hi @alexpdev and thank you for your help, i edited the post and added some lines that can help reproduce the example.

Comment: @aymane_da No, they cannot, as the code is still insufficient (where is the ui? what is `MainScreen`?). Also please verify that you're properly [formatting code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) by checking the post preview before submitting.